# Typo3 fileadmin security

Tags: typo3

I have a login area where I provide download links to files in a folder underneath fileadmin. How do I make absolutely sure that noone but a logged in user can obtain these files from the website?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `.htaccess` restriction.

Either restrict the access by htaccess-user (user/password)
or block direct access with htaccess and give access only to logged in TYPO3 users with extensions like [ext:secure_downloads](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/secure_downloads/)